# C++ template not recognizing data types

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following simplified code where the compiler is not recognizing the data types and I am not sure why.  In the code, I want to be able to pass a map, where the keywords can either be a `std::string`, a `char`, or an `int`.  I also want the user to be able to choose whether the associated value is a `float` or `double`.  In addition, based on the type of the associated value I want the return to either be  `std::vector<float>` or `std::vector<double>`.  Due to the variability in data types, I choose to code this problem as a template.

```
// main.cpp
#include "test.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

double func6(std::map<char, double> arr);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::map<char, double> inputs;
    inputs['x'] = 2.0;
    inputs['y'] = 5.438;

    std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>> answer;

    ODESolver q;
    answer = q.ode_solver(inputs, func6);
    // - The line below this was tried and it did not work 
    //   any better than the line of code above this.
    // answer = q.ode_solver<char, double>(inputs, func6);
    return 0;
}

double func6(std::map<char, double> arr)
{
    return arr['y'] * log(arr['y']) / arr['x'];
}
```

The .hpp file has the following information.

```
#ifndef test_hpp
#define test_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>


class ODESolver
{
public:
    template<class char_type, class real_type>
    static inline std::tuple<std::vector<real_type>, std::vector<real_type>>
    ode_solver(std::map<char_type, real_type> &inputs,
               const std::function<real_type(std::map<char_type, real_type>)>& func)
    {
        // - This function does not work with the function call 
        //   as written

        // - The code in this function is irrelevant, it was just 
        //   created to have returnable information of the correct 
        //   type to test the function call
        std::vector<real_type> one = {0.0, 1.0};
        std::vector<real_type> two = {0.0, 1.0};
        std::tuple<std::vector<real_type>, std::vector<real_type>> three(one, two);
        return three;
    }
};
#endif /* test_hpp */
```

The compiler does not allow the template shown above, because it does not recognize a matching function call for `answer= q.ode_solver(inputs, func6)` in the main program.  However, if I replace the `std::function` statement with the following code it works fine.

```
template<class char_type, class real_type>
static inline std::tuple<std::vector<real_type>, std::vector<real_type>>
ode_solver(std::map<char_type, real_type> &inputs,
           const std::function<double(std::map<char, double>)>& func)
```

All I am doing is replacing the templated parameters with the parameters I want to use in this exact situation, but that defeats the reason for using a template.  I have also tried calling the function with `answer = q.ode_solver<char, double>(inputs, func6)`; and it still does not recognize the function.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implicit conversions (from the function pointer to `std::function` in this case) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions).

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

You can add an explicit conversion, e.g.

```
answer = q.ode_solver(inputs, static_cast<std::function<double(std::map<char, double>)>>(func6));
```

or specify the template arguments explicitly (I'm not sure why you said it didn't work, see the live demo linked below)

```
answer = q.ode_solver<char, double>(inputs, func6);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AY0FMAYLBvsnplW6)

Or just add another template parameter instead of using `std::function`.

```
template<class char_type, class real_type, class F>
static inline std::tuple<std::vector<real_type>, std::vector<real_type>>
ode_solver(std::map<char_type, real_type> &inputs,
           const F& func)
```

Comment: You could also force the second parameter to be a non-deduced context, since deduction could succeed if looking at the first parameter only: ... `ode_solver(std::map<char_type, real_type> &inputs, type_identity_t<const std::function<double(std::map<char_type, real_type>)>&> func)` (`type_identity_t` is coming in C++20, but trivial to implement.) But I'd prefer the extra `F` parameter in your last snippet, since this allows directly using a lambda or other functor class, without the `std::function` overhead.